# Is there a way to get the controlled version of a AWS Braket Unitary?

Tags: programming, amazon-braket

In qiskit we can simply define a custom unitary $U$ and get its controlled version $C-U$ with the method `.control()`. So, is there a way to do the same in AWS Braket??

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/braket/latest/developerguide/braket-constructing-circuit.html
Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there yet exists a way to do this. What you could do is define your own control gate. For example:

```
import numpy as np

import itertools

import braket.ir.jaqcd as ir
from braket.circuits import Circuit, Instruction, Gate, circuit
from braket.circuits.gates import Unitary
from braket.circuits.qubit_set import QubitSet
```

```
class C(Gate):
    """Controlled gate
    Args:
        sub_gate (Gate): Quantum Gate.
        targets (QubitSet): Target qubits.
    """

    def __init__(self, sub_gate: Gate, targets: QubitSet):
        self.sub_gate = sub_gate
        qubit_count = len(targets)
        sub_qubit_count = sub_gate.qubit_count
        self._num_controls = qubit_count - sub_qubit_count
        self._controls = targets[: self._num_controls]
        ascii_symbols = ["C"] * self._num_controls + list(self.sub_gate.ascii_symbols)

        super().__init__(qubit_count=qubit_count, ascii_symbols=ascii_symbols)

    def _extend_matrix(self, sub_matrix: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        qid_shape = (2,) * self.qubit_count
        control_values = ((1,),) * self._num_controls
        sub_n = len(qid_shape) - self._num_controls
        tensor = np.eye(np.prod(qid_shape, dtype=np.int64).item(), dtype=sub_matrix.dtype)
        tensor.shape = qid_shape * 2
        sub_tensor = sub_matrix.reshape(qid_shape[self._num_controls :] * 2)
        for control_vals in itertools.product(*control_values):
            active = (*(v for v in control_vals), *(slice(None),) * sub_n) * 2
            tensor[active] = sub_tensor
        return tensor.reshape((np.prod(qid_shape, dtype=np.int64).item(),) * 2)

    def to_matrix(self, *args, **kwargs) -> np.ndarray:  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """Returns a matrix representation of the quantum operator
        Returns:
            np.ndarray: A matrix representation of the quantum operator
        """
        sub_matrix = self.sub_gate.to_matrix()
        return self._extend_matrix(sub_matrix)

    def to_ir(self, target: QubitSet):
        """Returns IR object of quantum operator and target
        Args:
            target (QubitSet): target qubit(s)
        Returns:
            IR object of the quantum operator and target
        """
        return ir.Unitary.construct(
            targets=list(target),
            matrix=C._transform_matrix_to_ir(self.to_matrix()),
        )

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, C):
            return self.matrix_equivalence(other)
        return NotImplemented

    @staticmethod
    def _transform_matrix_to_ir(matrix: np.ndarray):
        return [[[element.real, element.imag] for element in row] for row in matrix.tolist()]

    @staticmethod
    @circuit.subroutine(register=True)
    def c(targets: QubitSet, sub_gate: Gate) -> Instruction:
        """Registers this function into the circuit class.
        Args:
            targets (QubitSet): Target qubits.
            sub_gate (Gate): Quantum Gate.
        Returns:
            Instruction: Controlled Gate Instruction.
        """
        return Instruction(C(sub_gate, targets), target=targets)


Gate.register_gate(C)
```

First, defining a unitary matrix and gathering its dimension:

```
>>> matrix = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]])
>>> nqubits = int(np.log2(len(matrix)))
```

Next, adding the unitary gate to a circuit with no control:

```
>>> targets = list(range(nqubits))
>>> circ = Circuit().unitary(matrix=matrix, targets=targets)
>>> print(circ)
T  : |0|
        
q0 : -U-

T  : |0|
```

Finally, adding the unitary gate to a circuit with the control gate that we defined above:

```
>>> targets = list(range(nqubits+1))
>>> circ = Circuit().c(sub_gate=Unitary(matrix), targets=targets)
>>> print(circ)
T  : |0|
        
q0 : -C-
      | 
q1 : -U-

T  : |0|
```

Hopefully, in the future, there will be a more elegant way. But for now, this is my approach.

Comment: If I have a matrix, then it's fine, but what if I have U as a Circuit, and I want its control gate? Because `as_unitary()' method of AWS Braket Circuit class would slow down after 10  qubits. So is there a way I could directly get the controlled version of U from that circuit itself??

Comment: There's no Braket feature that explicitly does this, and I'm not familiar enough with their codebase to think of a workaround that wouldn't involve as_unitary or to_unitary. Your best bet is probably to go look at how qiskit implements their control method and see if you can map their procedure over to Braket in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

Update: as of version [1.40.0](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-sdk-python/releases/tag/v1.40.0), amazon-braket-sdk supports control and power modifiers. To make a controlled operation, use the `control` argument; for example, to attach a controlled-Hadamard gate with two control qubits to a circuit:

```python
circ = Circuit().h(2, control=[0, 1])
```